# Cannot find module

Tags: xcode

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: What did you do to cause this?  And since xcode is a Mac application, why are you using a WIndows path ("C"\c")?